# NexJS next-image not working on my server

Tags: docker, next.js, digital-ocean, next-images

Hello I have a website which is developed Nextjs.
I use Next Image for the images. When ı build my project and locally run it (yarn start) everything is fine .
[image]
But when ı want to run it on digitalocean server with ducker the images does not show . How can ı solve this?
[image]

Here next config file :

[image]

The error,
[image]

Here is my docker file .
https://gist.github.com/kubilaybzk/851946f91b8bffb7bb989be90c9b0669

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).